# Client posting parameters through octet-stream

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

We're moving away from our Jersey API's to spring mvc, this since we're using mostly spring for everything.

Now we've tested all our client's front-ends everything seems to work except one thing.

One of our clients uses an octet-stream type post request to send simple params (basically a set of ints and strings). We're not sure how to reproduce this and our application only consumes everything as `null` values.

We've got 5  converters set up `StringHttpMessageConverter`, `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`, `FormHttpMessageConverter` and a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

We've added a 5th `ByteArrayMessageConverter` trying to see if that would help but no. It seems like our old Jersey client did support this. Any idea's how to test this or consume this kind of message?

ask away.

(We can also test with MockMvc but we're not sure how to set the body since all we can find is people using this to test file uploads)

Our API's are set up pretty basic e.g.

```
private SomePojoWithGettersAndSetters foo(
    @RequestParam(required=false, "bar") bar, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, "foo") foo) {
//do something
}
```

The method is called, the params are just `null`.

We've realised the client is sending a normal form encoded string as in my comment below. we're currently scraping that in a custom converter but I'd rather see a more generic solution since what we do feels hacky imo.

Comment: Why have you explicitly setup the converters as Spring already sets them up for you (based on what it detects). Can you add the code that you have tried (controller and configuration).

Comment: There is some custom handling for json and xml basically (Like different posted date formats etc.). I'd rather have appended the default ones though agreed on that part.

We're currently scraping the body of the request successfully as it is a  normal parameter string param1=frank&param2=wilhelm etc.

I'll post an example our api is extremely basic. But I can't share the exact thing.

Comment: Why is it even posted as a stream? Is there a reason for it?

Comment: I'm not sure I think it's horrible coding on their side honestly. We got it working for now with a workaround :-(

Comment: I wonder why the `FormHttpMessageConverter` isn't working as that should support the mediatype for the stream. Maybe it is due to the configuration you have? Could you post it?

Comment: The FormHttpMessageConverter is added without any changes.

Maybe it doesn't pick up by default since it's a strange content-type?

Comment: Try adding `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` to the list of supported mediatypes. By default it only handles the normal/default form types. Just create a list containing `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` and `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` and `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`.